# Java iText  Image position

Tags: java, itext

I have:

```
   Image i = Image.getInstance("tabelka.png");
        i.scalePercent(25, 25);
    for(int i=0; i<= 5; i++)
    {
        doc.add(i);

        content.moveTo(50, ??);////// <-------------- HOW TO CHECK THE Y POSITION
        content.showText("skowron-line");
    }
```

I want to set text on upper right corner of image. How do I do that?

EIDT:
After hours of thinkin i found dirty solution:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance("tabelka.png");
img.scalePercent(25, 25);
float start = x;
for(int i =1; i<= 5; i++)
{
  start = (x - (img.getHeight() * 0.25f) * i);
}
```

If U know better solution let me know.

Comment: this is a pdf file, and doc is `Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);`

Answer (score 0):

To know where on the page a given element is, you need to give it a generic tag and register a `PdfPageEvent` with your `PdfWriter`.

To draw text at a specific location, you must draw it directly to a `PdfContentByte`.  Note that "directly" isn't all that direct when you can still build a paragraph and call `ColumnText.showTextAligned()`.

Down to specifics

To give an `Image` a generic tag, you must wrap it in a chunk:

```
Chunk imgChunk = new Chunk( img, 0, 0 );
imgChunk.setGenericTag("imgTag");
```

Then you set up a `PdfPageEvent` handler with an onGenericTag callback that will draw your text:

```
myPdfWriter.setPageEvent( new PdfPageEventHelper() {
  public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, Rectangle chunkRect, String tag ) {
    if ("imgTag".equals(tag)) {
      // Draw your text into that rect.
      ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getOverContent(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, paragraph,
        chunkRect.getLeft() + someOffsetX, chunkRect.getTop() - someOffsetY, 0f );
    }
  }
} );
```

`PdfPageEventHelper` is an empty implementation of the `PdfPageEvent` interface.  We override the method we care about and away we go.